# AVX inside a VirtualBox VM?

Tags: ubuntu, x86, virtualbox, avx

I install the latest Ubuntu 14.04 amd64(gcc 4.8.2) in virtualbox, run cat /proc/cpuinfo, get result:
[image: CPUINFO]

The processor CORE i52520M does support AVX instructions. I used Ubuntu 12.04 amd64(gcc 4.6), and it supports AVX via /proc/cpuinfo.

How can I use the AVX in my software in virtualbox?

Comment: As far as I can tell, VirtualBox does not support AVX (https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=48732)

Comment: OK, I see. According to the result above, I think virtualbox even dose not support SSE4.x.

Comment: @NorbertP. that's an ancient thread though, is there a more recent source to quote?

Comment: https://www.virtualbox.org/ticket/12206

Comment: No version of VirtualBox I have used supports AVX yet.  If I remember correctly VMware does but I can't confirm this.

Comment: I'm using ubuntu 12.04 in virtualbox and I have the save problem too. It can't even support SSE4.1 and SSE4.2 just like  your screenshot

Comment: [VirtualBox 5.0 beta 3 now supports AVX and AVX2](http://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=news_item&px=VirtualBox-5.0-Beta-3) and SSE4.2

Answer (score 3):

[VirtualBox 5.0 beta 3 now supports AVX and AVX2](http://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=news_item&px=VirtualBox-5.0-Beta-3) (which I can confirm from testing).

Comment: VirtualBox 5.0 beta 3 is too unstable in practice for me.

Comment: But VirtualBox 5.0 RC2 seems to be stable so far.

Comment: It looks like AVX2 was disabled temporarily, I wrote an answer with more info and how to re-enable it on AskUbuntu: http://askubuntu.com/q/699077/40581