# OpenCL demo program works on one system, but not on an other very similar VirtualBox system

Tags: c, vagrant, opencl, virtualbox, sse

I am trying out the following simple OpenCL vector addition program (I have not included my printSystemInfo() function for brevity):

```
// Vector addition demo similar to one from Oak Ridge lab:
// https://www.olcf.ornl.gov/tutorials/opencl-vector-addition/#vecAdd.c


#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

//To suppress warnings when using the deprecated clCreateCommandQueue of OpenCL v1.0:
#define CL_USE_DEPRECATED_OPENCL_2_0_APIS

#include <math.h>
#include <CL/opencl.h>

// Declaration of a printing function, that is not seen at this StackOverflow question
int printSystemInfo (cl_platform_id platform_id, cl_device_id device_id);

// OpenCL kernel. Each work item takes care of one element of vector c
const char *kernelSource =                                       "\n" \
"__kernel void vecAdd(  __global int *a,                       \n" \
"                       __global int *b,                       \n" \
"                       __global int *c,                       \n" \
"                       const unsigned int n)                    \n" \
"{                                                               \n" \
"    //Get our global thread ID                                  \n" \
"    int id = get_global_id(0);                                  \n" \
"                                                                \n" \
"    //Make sure we do not go out of bounds                      \n" \
"    if (id < n)                                                 \n" \
"        c[id] = a[id] + b[id];                                  \n" \
"}                                                               \n" \
                                                                "\n" ;

int main( int argc, char* argv[] )
{
    // Length of vectors
    unsigned int n = 10;

    // Host input vectors
    int *h_a;
    int *h_b;
    // Host output vector
    int *h_c;

    // Device input buffers
    cl_mem d_a;
    cl_mem d_b;
    // Device output buffer
    cl_mem d_c;

    cl_platform_id platform_id;        // OpenCL platform
    cl_device_id device_id;           // device ID
    cl_context context;               // context
    cl_command_queue queue;           // command queue
    cl_program program;               // program
    cl_kernel kernel;                 // kernel

    // Size, in bytes, of each vector
    size_t bytes = n*sizeof(int);

    // Allocate memory for each vector on host
    h_a = (int*)malloc(bytes);
    h_b = (int*)malloc(bytes);
    h_c = (int*)malloc(bytes);

    // Initialize vectors on host
    int i;
    for( i = 0; i < n; i++ )
    {
        h_a[i] = i;
        h_b[i] = i+1;
    }

    size_t globalSize, localSize;
    cl_int err;

    // Number of work items in each local work group
    localSize = 64;

    // Number of total work items - localSize must be a divisor
    globalSize = ceil(n/(float)localSize)*localSize;

    // Bind to platform
    err = clGetPlatformIDs(1, &platform_id, NULL);

    // Get ID for the device
    //err = clGetDeviceIDs(cpPlatform, CL_DEVICE_TYPE_GPU, 1, &device_id, NULL);
    err = clGetDeviceIDs(platform_id, CL_DEVICE_TYPE_CPU, 1, &device_id, NULL);

    // Call a local function that fetches and prints system info
    err = printSystemInfo (platform_id, device_id);

    // Create a context
    context = clCreateContext(0, 1, &device_id, NULL, NULL, &err);

    // Create a command queue
    queue = clCreateCommandQueue(context, device_id, 0, &err);

    // Create the compute program from the source buffer
    program = clCreateProgramWithSource(context, 1,
                            (const char **) & kernelSource, NULL, &err);

    // Build the program executable
    clBuildProgram(program, 0, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL);

    // Create the compute kernel in the program we wish to run
    kernel = clCreateKernel(program, "vecAdd", &err);

    // Create the input and output arrays in device memory for our calculation
    d_a = clCreateBuffer(context, CL_MEM_READ_ONLY, bytes, NULL, NULL);
    d_b = clCreateBuffer(context, CL_MEM_READ_ONLY, bytes, NULL, NULL);
    d_c = clCreateBuffer(context, CL_MEM_WRITE_ONLY, bytes, NULL, NULL);

    // Write our data set into the input array in device memory
    err = clEnqueueWriteBuffer(queue, d_a, CL_TRUE, 0,
                                   bytes, h_a, 0, NULL, NULL);
    err |= clEnqueueWriteBuffer(queue, d_b, CL_TRUE, 0,
                                   bytes, h_b, 0, NULL, NULL);

    // Set the arguments to our compute kernel
    err  = clSetKernelArg(kernel, 0, sizeof(cl_mem), &d_a);
    err |= clSetKernelArg(kernel, 1, sizeof(cl_mem), &d_b);
    err |= clSetKernelArg(kernel, 2, sizeof(cl_mem), &d_c);
    err |= clSetKernelArg(kernel, 3, sizeof(unsigned int), &n);

    // Execute the kernel over the entire range of the data set
    err = clEnqueueNDRangeKernel(queue, kernel, 1, NULL, &globalSize, &localSize,
                                                              0, NULL, NULL);

    // Wait for the command queue to get serviced before reading back results
    clFinish(queue);

    // Read the results from the device
    clEnqueueReadBuffer(queue, d_c, CL_TRUE, 0,
                                bytes, h_c, 0, NULL, NULL );

    //Print vectors a, b and c=a+b
    for(i=0; i<n; i++)
        printf("a: %d  b: %d  c=a+b: %d \n", h_a[i], h_b[i], h_c[i] );

    // release OpenCL resources
    clReleaseMemObject(d_a);
    clReleaseMemObject(d_b);
    clReleaseMemObject(d_c);
    clReleaseProgram(program);
    clReleaseKernel(kernel);
    clReleaseCommandQueue(queue);
    clReleaseContext(context);

    //release host memory
    free(h_a);
    free(h_b);
    free(h_c);

    return 0;
}
```

It works on an Amazon EC2 system running Ubuntu 14.04...

```
ubuntu@ip-xxx:~/programs/OpenCL$ gcc ./cldemo.c ./printSystemInfo.c  -o ./cldemo -I/opt/intel/intel-opencl-1.2-5.0.0.43/opencl-1.2-sdk-5.0.0.43/include -L/opt/intel/intel-opencl-1.2-5.0.0.43/opencl-1.2-5.0.0.43/lib64 -lOpenCL -Wall -lm

ubuntu@ip-xxx:~/programs/OpenCL$ ./cldemo

OS name: Linux
Release:3.13.0-52-generic
Version:#86-Ubuntu SMP Mon May 4 04:32:59 UTC 2015
Machine:x86_64

Platform name = Intel(R) OpenCL
Platform version = OpenCL 1.2 LINUX
Platform extensions = cl_khr_icd cl_khr_global_int32_base_atomics cl_khr_global_int32_extended_atomics cl_khr_local_int32_base_atomics cl_khr_local_int32_extended_atomics cl_khr_byte_addressable_store cl_khr_depth_images cl_khr_3d_image_writes cl_intel_exec_by_local_thread cl_khr_spir cl_khr_fp64

Device name =       Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2670 v2 @ 2.50GHz
Device version = OpenCL 1.2 (Build 43)
Device global memory size= 1040740352
Device extensions= cl_khr_icd cl_khr_global_int32_base_atomics cl_khr_global_int32_extended_atomics cl_khr_local_int32_base_atomics cl_khr_local_int32_extended_atomics cl_khr_byte_addressable_store cl_khr_depth_images cl_khr_3d_image_writes cl_intel_exec_by_local_thread cl_khr_spir cl_khr_fp64

a: 0  b: 1  c=a+b: 1
a: 1  b: 2  c=a+b: 3
a: 2  b: 3  c=a+b: 5
a: 3  b: 4  c=a+b: 7
a: 4  b: 5  c=a+b: 9
a: 5  b: 6  c=a+b: 11
a: 6  b: 7  c=a+b: 13
a: 7  b: 8  c=a+b: 15
a: 8  b: 9  c=a+b: 17
a: 9  b: 10  c=a+b: 19
```

But not on a similar system at home (but with the Ubuntu 14.04 running as a Vagrant VirtualBox machine inside a Windows 7 host):

```
OS name: Linux 
Release:3.13.0-53-generic 
Version:#89-Ubuntu SMP Wed May 20 10:34:39 UTC 2015 
Machine:x86_64 

Platform name = Intel(R) OpenCL 
Platform version = OpenCL 1.2 LINUX 
Platform extensions = cl_khr_icd cl_khr_global_int32_base_atomics cl_khr_global_int32_extended_atomics cl_khr_local_int32_base_atomics cl_khr_local_int32_extended_atomics cl_khr_byte_addressable_store cl_khr_depth_images cl_khr_3d_image_writes cl_intel_exec_by_local_thread cl_khr_spir  

Device name =        Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-2620M CPU @ 2.70GHz 
Device version = OpenCL 1.2 (Build 43) 
Device global memory size= 3156189184
Device extensions= cl_khr_icd cl_khr_global_int32_base_atomics cl_khr_global_int32_extended_atomics cl_khr_local_int32_base_atomics cl_khr_local_int32_extended_atomics cl_khr_byte_addressable_store cl_khr_depth_images cl_khr_3d_image_writes cl_intel_exec_by_local_thread cl_khr_spir  

a: 0  b: 1  c=a+b: 0 
a: 1  b: 2  c=a+b: 0 
a: 2  b: 3  c=a+b: 0 
a: 3  b: 4  c=a+b: 0 
a: 4  b: 5  c=a+b: 0 
a: 5  b: 6  c=a+b: 0 
a: 6  b: 7  c=a+b: 0 
a: 7  b: 8  c=a+b: 0 
a: 8  b: 9  c=a+b: 0 
a: 9  b: 10  c=a+b: 0
```

I am new to OpenCL. Any helpful pointers would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Try calling `clGetDeviceInfo` with the `CL_DEVICE_AVAILABLE` query. I seem to remember also having problems with Intel's OpenCL implementation in a virtual machine.

Comment: Thanks! That did point me in the right direction. I will post my solution below, if it helps.

Comment: [VitualBox 5.0 beta3 now supports SSE4.1, SSE4.2, and AVX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24543874/does-ubuntu-14-04-support-avx-extension/30299294#30299294). So if you use VB 5.0 beta3 Intel OpenCL should work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As others have said here, Intel's OpenCL SDK does not work out of the box on a VirtualBox. Apparently, the SDK requires that the CPU support SIMD extensions SSE4_1 and SSE4_2, but VirtualBox's default settings are turned off for them (can check with: `cat /proc/cpuinfo` )

So, open the host (Windows, in my case) console, go to the VirtualBox installation directory and enter:

```
VBoxManage setextradata "your-VM-name" VBoxInternal/CPUM/SSE4.1 1
VBoxManage setextradata "your-VM-name" VBoxInternal/CPUM/SSE4.2 1
```

Now restart the VM, and OpenCL should work (at least it did for me).

Comment: I didn't know such options exist, I did enable SSE4.1/2 for my VM and I can see they are there. I'm not going to check if Intel OpenCL is working, don't want to mess with it as I have AMD one installed already :) Thanks!

Comment: You are welcome. I am already onto another problem now - I see the cl_khr_fp64 extension (needed for double precision) on the Amazon's Ubuntu+Intel, and see it online for others with same Intel processor as mine, but i dont see it on my home system above. Sigh! I might go with AMD after all.

Comment: This is interesting! I'm surprised by this. Why would these be disabled by default? Anyway [VB 5.0 beta3 now supports them as well as AVX and AVX2 by default](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24543874/does-ubuntu-14-04-support-avx-extension/30299294#30299294).

Comment: @Zboson: Possibly for migrating machine state to older machines that don't support those instruction sets.  (I haven't used vbox for a while, but I assume it lets you hibernate your VM and then resume on a different machine.  This only works if the other machine supports all the CPU features exposed by the VM.)

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't make work Intel OpenCL using Intel SDK/drivers on Ubuntu 14.04 under VirtualBox either. You can install AMD APP SDK if that makes no difference to you (it shouldn't), it works very well on Intel CPU.

Link:
[AMD APP SDK](http://developer.amd.com/tools-and-sdks/opencl-zone/amd-accelerated-parallel-processing-app-sdk/)

Comment: You were right - Intel OpenCL SDK does have some issues with VirtualBox. I will paste my solution, in case it helps anyone.