# gdb reverse debugging avx2

Tags: c, gdb, glibc, avx2

So I have a new fancy cpu that supports avx2 instruction set. 
This is great, but breaks gdb reverse debugging. When compiling with no optimisations code still uses shared libraries, eg calls memset() which then goes and invokes an avx2 optimised version of memset. This is great but avx2 is not supported by gdb record.

process record does not support instruction 0xc5 at address 0x7ffff690dd80.

0xc5 is the vex prefix here.

reverse debugging works great with a cpu that does not support avx2. How do I get libc etc to not use the avx2 optimised versions of library calls so I can use gdb record, step backwards etc?

I've tried

```
LD_BIND_NOW=1
LD_HWCAP_MASK=0
compiling with -static
```

And short of debugging on an old machine, I'm out of ideas.

Comment: What version of GLIBC are you using?

Comment: 2.23 as shipped on ubuntu 16.04 amd64 arch. cpu is an i7 xeon that supports avx2

Comment: Was already asked here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/42451492/72178.

Comment: Probably build with old GLIBC ?

Comment: You could try a [pre-5.0 version of virtualbox](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24543874/avx-inside-a-virtualbox-vm)

Comment: Hello. As required, I just documented my kludge in the: stackoverflow.com/q/42451492 as https://stackoverflow.com/a/44468494 (`jg` bit patched manually into `jle` to disable all avx2 detection in the `ld-linux.so.2`)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Disable AVX-optimized functions in glibc (LD\_HWCAP\_MASK, /etc/ld.so.nohwcap) for valgrind & gdb record](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42451492/disable-avx-optimized-functions-in-glibc-ld-hwcap-mask-etc-ld-so-nohwcap-for)

Comment: I compiled with -static and the problem went away for me

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61048314/594456

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your glibc 2.23 as shipped on ubuntu 16.04 amd64 there is adaptation of [my binary kludge (1 bit patch)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44468494/196561) made exactly for the same reason. Package `libc6 (2.23-0ubuntu7)` was downloaded from https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/amd64/libc6 and file ld-2.23.so was edited (keep copy of the original, or save patched into different path and change INTERP section of your own binary to use different path):

```
 83 3D 5B C9 20 00 06   cmpl $0x6, smth...
 7E 21                  jle  some_forward_label
 B8 07 00 00 00         mov $0x7, %eax
 31 C9                  xor %ecx,%ecx
 0F A2                  cpuid
```

There is code of [the `get_common_indeces`: `if (cpu_features->max_cpuid >= 7) __cpuid_count (7, 0, ...`](https://github.com/bminor/glibc/blob/glibc-2.25/sysdeps/x86/cpu-features.c#L45) called from `__get_cpu_features`. [EAX=7 leaf of cpuid has all info needed to detect AVX2 support and enable it](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CPUID#EAX.3D7.2C_ECX.3D0:_Extended_Features), so I just skipped fragment with `cpuid eax=0x7,ecx=0` and saving its results into some parts of memory by changing [`0x7e 0x21` into `0x7f 0x21`](http://ref.x86asm.net/coder64.html#x7E).

So, the binary patch is like replacing `83 3D xx xx xx xx 06  7E xx  B8 07 00 00 00  31 C9  0F A2` (where xx may be any byte) into `83 3D xx xx xx xx 06  7F xx  B8 07 00 00 00  31 C9  0F A2`. You may do this with any Hex Editor or by some binary diff. In 2.23-0ubuntu7 this code is at 0x0193B0 - 0x0193B9 is 7e to be changed into 7f.

The patch it dumb and don't use patched file globally if your root fs may be started with CPU without eax=7 cpuid leaf support (pre Intel Core CPU) or in virtual machine emulating such pre Intel Core CPU (["Pentium D 8xx/9xx", Pentium 4, Pentium M - will fail](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CPUID#EAX.3D0:_Highest_Function_Parameter)).

You may put patched file at path which name is equal in length or shorter to the original path of `/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2` (which symlinks into `/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.23.so` file). For example as `/lib_x86_64-linux-gnu_ld-linux-noAVX2.so.2`. Then use same hexeditor to replace the string "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2" of your program executable (ELF) into "/lib_x86_64-linux-gnu_ld-linux-noAVX2.so.2", or use patchelf tool [from the `patchelf` package](https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/amd64/patchelf/filelist):

```
cp /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.23.so /lib_x86_64-linux-gnu_ld-linux-noAVX2.so.2

bless  /lib_x86_64-linux-gnu_ld-linux-noAVX2.so.2
# or any other hex editor

patchelf --set-interpreter /lib_x86_64-linux-gnu_ld-linux-no-AVX2.so.2 ./my_program
```

Comment: If I could award retrospective bounty on an answer this would qualify. Fantastic content, well written and the solution checked out and was used successfully. Cheers.

Comment: @Hal, There should be "start a bounty" button below the question with reason of "Reward existing answer - One or more of the answers is exemplary and worthy of an additional bounty". Answer should be checked/updated to 18.04 LTS; and in some linked question there was scripted binary patch (no manual binary editing), probably in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42451492 with  `re.sub` of the python. Another solution: check https://github.com/mozilla/rr RR reverse debugging tool from Mozilla for Firefox (thanks to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42451492#comment79266853_42451492).

Comment: For some reason this method didn't work for me on Ubuntu 16.04 as of today (25/04/19). But the Python script in this answer patches something slightly different and did work: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42451492/disable-avx-optimized-functions-in-glibc-ld-hwcap-mask-etc-ld-so-nohwcap-for?rq=1